# gazebo_client.hh not found

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=topics_subscribed&cat=transport) but when I tried to compile it shows

[image: image description]

I tried to remove gazebo client related codes and include, and got it compiled, but the subscriber never calls the callback function to print.

I am using Gazebo 5. What is wrong here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8865/gazebo_client.hh-not-found/) by [mugenHexapod](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1197/mugenhexapod/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2015-06-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PML](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1147/pml/) on 2015-06-04**:
Just to zoom a little bit more on the problem, are the gazebo developer libraries installed on your computer?

**Comment by [mugenHexapod](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1197/mugenhexapod/) on 2015-06-04**:
libgazebo5-dev right? I did have it installed.

**Comment by [PML](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1147/pml/) on 2015-06-04**:
Actually i downloaded the same files and got the very same error, client.hh does not exist, since i did this tutorial a few months ago i compared the files and found that in the earlier version

<gazebo/gazebo_client.hh> is <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
gazebo::client::setup is gazebo::setupClient
gazebo::client::shutdown() is gazebo::shutdown()

So the question that should be asked is how to get the new developer libraries that include this new client.hh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found the problem. The tutorial uses [this file](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/raw/default/examples/stand_alone/listener/listener.cc). It's probably outdated. And I looked into the source code and found the listener example for Gazebo 5. This is the [right file](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/raw/0454926303b81b1538826020d71de38e6cd06b7d/examples/stand_alone/listener/listener.cc). Got it compiled and printing world info now.

---

Originally posted by [mugenHexapod](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1197/mugenhexapod/) with karma: 17 on 2015-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0